# Connect to SQL Through VBA Code Issues

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a code that runs at the DB startup to run some querys and update some tables. I am trying to setup a code that connects to the external source of the linked data tables so I don't have to enter the password each time. I keep getting an odd error though, the login window still popsup but the information is prepopulated, when I click ok I get another error message. I have displayed the code and error window below.

```
Function MasterRun()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

Dim strConn As String

strConn = strConn & "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=SOURCE;"
strConn = strConn & "INITIAL CATALOG=DB;"
strConn = strConn & "UID=User;"
strConn = strConn & "PWD=Password;"
conn.ConnectionString = strConn
conn.Open

On Error GoTo MasterRun_Err
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
StartUp
Update
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_V_TMS_EMPLOYEE", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.Save acQuery, "qry_V_TMS_EMPLOYEE"
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qry_V_TMS_EMPLOYEE"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry2013CDMtg", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.Save acQuery, "qry2013CDMtg"
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qry2013CDMtg"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdateEmpData", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCDData"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox ("The database has been updated and is ready for use.")

MasterRun_Exit:
Exit Function

MasterRun_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume MasterRun_Exit

End Function
```

And below is the login window that pops up. This is the window that popped up before I even started trying to write in this connection code.

[image]

### Edit

I have reposted a revision of this question, I have thought of a different way to establish the connection.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/22540898/2144390

Comment: What happens if you uncheck the Use Trusted Connection?  You shouldn't need windows authentication _and_ the credentials.

Comment: It continues with the process, but then the login window appears anyway, do I have the code in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you able to connect directly to SQL server without using credentials?  Try commenting out this line also `strConn = strConn & "Trusted_connection=no;"` as it's doing the opposite of `strConn = strConn & "INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"`

Comment: I removed both those lines and it continutes with the process again, but still asks for the login information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be multiple issues involved with your question, but the first which jumps out at me is that you want *"so I don't have to enter the password each time"*.

But your code includes ...

```vb
conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
```

That line means *"ask me for user name and password every time I open the connection".*  That is the opposite of your intention.

Remove that line and see what other problems remain.

As more general advice, focus on the immediate problem ... which is the failed connection attempt.  So focus only on that ...

```vb
Public Sub TestConnection()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
' you already created the connection object in the line above,
' so CreateObject is not useful:
'Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim strConn As String

strConn = "PROVIDER= ..." ' this is where you need work
' make sure you built the connection string you expected;
' view the output from the next line in the Immediate window ---
' Ctrl+g will take you there
Debug.Print strConn
conn.ConnectionString = strConn
conn.Open
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a RUN TIME ERROR saying Login Failed and it highlights the CONN.OPEN portion of the code.

Comment: @user2119980: That means your username and / or password are incorrect. Can you log in with those credentials with SQL Server Management Studio for example?

Comment: Yes I use those credentials everytime I login

Comment: The error message indicates you're attempting to login as user `VZV7KQM` at domain `US`.  Is that the account you're using to connect in SQL Server Management studio?  BTW, why did you obscure Login ID in the SQL Server Login dialog ... isn't the Login ID the same one displayed in the error message?

Comment: No it is a different login, I am not sure why it is displaying that as my login.

Comment: @HansUp I made the edits you listed above but I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 4):

According to the error message the username or password is incorrect. This would probably be the reason you get this connect dialog again.

Alter your code to include the correct username and password. Check the `State` in the error message to know what field was actually wrong.

See this useful reference: [Understanding "login failed" (Error 18456) error messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx).

Also I want to note that your connection string is conflicting: you define both `User ID` and `Password` and `SSPI`, but not `Trusted_Connection`, which is the same as `SSPI`.

**EDIT:**

Are you sure you are logging in with the username and password you provided? As in my answer already, and brought up by @HansUp again: the error message shows a domain name, I guess that differs from the username and password you provided in code (since you cannot log in using Windows username and password in SQL without using SSPI). **Remove the SSPI from your connection string!**

Comment: But its the same login info I use every time

Comment: I did that, and that one pop up no longer appears, but it still asks for the login information in a different window that normally pops up in this scenario.

Comment: It is not an error message, it is just a different login screen.

Comment: It is the login screen I would get if I didn't even have the connection code in there pretty much

Comment: I am back to the original problem, I made the edits to the code and the original issue I posted about was resolved. BUT I still get the login window that would appear if the connection code wasn't even there.

Comment: I will change the code above to reflect what it looks like now.

Comment: @user2119980: After what line this dialog is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this section:

```
strConn = strConn & "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=SERVER;"
strConn = strConn & "INITIAL CATALOG=DB;"
strConn = strConn & "User ID=ID;"
strConn = strConn & "Password=PASSWORD;"
strConn = strConn & "INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
strConn = strConn & "Trusted_connection=no;"
conn.ConnectionString = strConn
conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
conn.Open
```

with this:

```
strConn = strConn & "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=YourActualServer;"
strConn = strConn & "INITIAL CATALOG=YourActualDatabase;"
strConn = strConn & "UID=YourActualUserID;"
strConn = strConn & "PWD=YourActualPassword;"
conn.ConnectionString = strConn
conn.Open
```

Comment: I still get the original login window. It is the original login window I would get if this code was not even there

Comment: Weird.  I use that exact block of code in all my apps and I don't get the login window.  What about if you replace UID and PWD with **TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes;**?  I just answered this question a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407760/code-to-eliminate-need-to-enter-password/22412437#22412437

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm using 2008 too.  I don't know, maybe this is more about a DBA's role?  Could there be some permissions issue on your server that prevents you from connecting without specifically logging in?  I'm on the programming side, I don't deal with the DBA side.

Comment: Also, just wondering if you've stepped through the code.  Is this definitely happening when you open the connection, or are you prompted when you try to run the first query?

Comment: The login window pops up when the DB is opened. I have a macro code that initiates a number of tasks when the DB opens, one of which is running a make table query that is made up of other queries containing linked tables to the Server I am trying to connect to. I have tried all kinds of codes in different areas of the VBA and I keep getting the login window pictured above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50164/discussion-between-user2119980-and-johnny-bones)

Comment: Right after you open the connection in your VBA, and before you run **Startup** (I'm assuming that's a function?), put a messagebox that says, "Hi" or something.  Then, when you run it, if you get the messagebox first you will know the connection is fine.  If you get the login box first, you will kno wthe connection requires the login.  This way you can try to pinpoint exactly where in your code the login box is being called.  About the chat, I gotta get back to the work I'm getting paid for.  :o)  I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: I did that and the message box popped up first.

Comment: What could that mean?

Comment: I have a conference call in 8 minutes, but I just saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540898/editing-a-connection-code-in-access  How many times are you opening a connection to this DB?  Open it once, and that's it.  As for the messagebox popping up first, that tells me the connection is open.  Your problem isn't in your connection string, it's somewhere else.  If you're, in fact, opening a connection multiple times, that's an issue.  Keep moving the messagebox around until you get the login screen first, and then you'll know exactly where the problem is.

Comment: THat is the only other connection, the purpose of that one is to establish a connection with a DIFFERENT sql server and then copy data in. This one is for a different Sql Server